# Xdebug 3 on GitPod with Apache

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug, xdebug-3, gitpod

I am trying to get Xdebug 3 to run on GitPod with Apache. Installation works well, also "Launch on currently open script".

The challenge is to connect Xdebug to the debug client. That seems to fail if one is just using `xdebug.client_host = localhost`, because of the Docker environment. Normally one would use `xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal`, but simply declaring that does not work on GitPod.

Comment: *"The challenge is to connect Xdebug to the webserver."* What do you mean here? I believe you need to RTM on what Xdebug is and how it works. Just in case: 1) Xdebug is PHP extension. So it's already "connected to the website" since it is loaded together with other PHP extensions (if installed and configured ofc)

Comment: 2) It's Xdebug that connects to debug client (VSCode in your case) and NOT other way around. That's why I think that this `- port: 9003` line is not needed (as I understand it opens port from container so it can be reached from the host OS). That's why `xdebug.client_host = localhost` would also not good here (at least not for traditional Docker where you would normally use `xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal`). Not sure what needs to be used for GitPod (do not really know how it actually works)... but Xdebug must be able to connect to your debug client/VSCode.

Comment: 3) I'm sure that in your research you must have checked a lot of links. But just in case: does this one provide any help? https://www.gitpod.io/docs/introduction/languages/php#debugging-php-in-gitpod

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks, updated the question. Indeed, ````xdebug.client_host = host.docker.internal`` is a likely solution in the Ubuntu docker environment of GitPod. I think https://github.com/tmy2017/php-ddd-cargo-sample/commit/ca57066712aba5dbd4542ffd9242f21b23e338f4 shows some solution via ``docker run --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway`` but I don't know how to implement this in my use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help on the Gitpod Discord, here is the solution. It is implemented in [the repo on Github](https://github.com/Eetezadi/Gitpod-Apache-PHP-Xdebug).

No changes or pathmappings in VScode needed. Default `launch.json` works.

Xdebug settings for "Listen to Xd" to be copied to Apache (e.g. /etc/php/8.2/apache2/conf.d/99-custom.ini)

```
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
```

Xdebug settings for CLI to be copied (e.g. /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/)

```
xdebug.mode = off
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

Docker caches the copy commands and this can lead to a lot of confusion when debugging. So I moved them to the .gitpod.yml, which also initializes the ports and installs the php-debug extension for VScode.

```
image:
  file: .gitpod.dockerfile
  context: .env
  
ports:
- port: 8080
  onOpen: open-preview
- port: 9003
  onOpen: ignore

tasks:
- name: Apache
  init: >
    sudo cp .env/xdebug_cli.ini /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/99-custom.ini &&
    sudo cp .env/xdebug_web.ini /etc/php/8.2/apache2/conf.d/99-custom.ini
  command: >
    apachectl start &&
    multitail /var/log/apache2/access.log -I /var/log/apache2/error.log

vscode:
  extensions:
    - felixfbecker.php-debug
```

Comment: Good catch. Upvoted. That does directly address Xdebug settings and avoids potential permission issues by not altering Docker daemon configurations.

Answer (score 0):

> I think [tmy2017/php-ddd-cargo-sample `xdebug.ini`](https://github.com/tmy2017/php-ddd-cargo-sample/commit/ca57066712aba5dbd4542ffd9242f21b23e338f4) shows some solution via `docker run --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway`, but I don't know how to implement this in my use case?

To implement this in your Gitpod setup, you might need to update the custom Docker image and incorporate a similar `extra_hosts` configuration.

`.gitpod.dockerfile`:

```
FROM gitpod/workspace-full:latest

# rest of your code

USER root
# Add extra_hosts configuration
RUN echo "extra_hosts:" >> /etc/docker/daemon.json && \
    echo "  - host.docker.internal:host-gateway" >> /etc/docker/daemon.json
USER gitpod

# rest of your code
```

That would include the `extra_hosts` configuration similar to the one in the `docker-compose.yml` from the provided GitHub commit.
That way, you can check if `host.docker.internal` can be resolved correctly within your Gitpod environment.

Comment: I tried this here: https://github.com/Eetezadi/Gitpod-Apache-PHP-Xdebug/tree/daemonjson Fails with permission denied.

Comment: @Sina Can you add a `RUN id -a` before `RUN echo "extra_hosts:" >> /etc/docker/daemon.json`? If you are not root, that would fail with "permission denied". A `USER root` might be needed (followed by a `USER xxx` to restore the user in place before)

Comment: It returns, so AFAIK it runs as sudo: #7 0.248 uid=33333(gitpod) gid=33333(gitpod) groups=33333(gitpod),27(sudo),107(nixbld)

Comment: @Sina OK, so `USER root` before the `RUN echo`, and `USER gitpod` after. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Good news, it opens. But then again: "Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:44309 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port)"

Comment: @Sina The error suggests Xdebug is trying to connect to the debug client on a different port (44309). Ensure that `xdebug.client_port` is set to `9003` in `xdebug.ini` and `launch.json`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255750/discussion-between-sina-and-vonc).